# How can I change the language in the ProfileManager?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

My standard language for Firefox and Thunderbird is Dutch.
When I use the terminal to open firefox or thunderbird with the -ProfileManager option, the resulting ProfileManager is in English.
How can I change the language to Dutch in the ProfileManager?

Comment: You mean that only profile manager is English while the main app is in Dutch?

Comment: How did you get your Firefox into Dutch? Was it with an Add-On?  If so, note that Add-Ons are Firefox-profile-specific, so they won't affect Profile Manager.  If I download an actual Dutch-localized version of Firefox directly from Mozilla (from http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all.html ), its ProfileManager opens up in Dutch for me.

Comment: I did install firefox-locale-nl only

Comment: The firefox-locale-nl .deb package installs a Firefox addon and search plugin for use in profiles, rather than customizing the actual profile-independent firefox installation.  See `dpkg -L firefox-locale-nl` -- that shows that the package just adds files in /usr/lib/firefox-addons and /usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a fully localized version of Firefox here:
  http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all.html
and then extract that in e.g. `/home/{yourusername}/programs/firefox/`

Then, create a directory `/home/{yourusername}/bin/` and create a symbolic link "firefox" in that directory, pointing to `/home/{yourusername}/programs/firefox/firefox`.

Starting from the next time you log in, all invocations of "firefox" (including through the system menus) should invoke your own localized version of Firefox instead of the Ubuntu-maintained version.

(This is what I do, because I'm using a nightly build of Firefox instead of the Ubuntu-maintained version.)